# Salesforce1 - Error while Accessing Community in Salesforce1 Mobile Application

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile

We are trying to make use of Salesforce1 Mobile app for allowing user to use our community. Using the Community Login URL, i have added the server from "Change Server" option in the top right menu. Now, our community login page(Custom VF Page) loads up at first.

Once community user enters username and password, it redirects them to the landing page (Custom VF page). After login, there is another option in top right menu as 'Reload'. 
This is for reloading the page, but if we do reload,
takes the logged in user to a standard community page of the Salesforce1 mobile application.

I need our community VF pages to be displayed after reload option or is there any way we can remove the reload option from the Salesforce1 mobile app?

Here i am attaching the screenshots as per above explanation,

[image: First page]

This is my initial Screenshot here we Setup Server URL (by providing a Name and Community URL) and on clicking Apply button redirects user to login page (which is custom VF page as shown below:

[image: Second page]

Above Screenshot entering Username and password, will authenticate and redirects user to our custom landing page (VF page) as shown in below screenshot:

[image: third page]

There is a provision on top right corner, by clicking on it, a small menu will appear as shown below,

[image: Fourth page]

If we select the 3rd option that is reload, then the salesforce1 app displays the standard community page of the Salesforce1 mobile application shown below:

[image: Fifth page]

Even after reload, how should i take my logged in user to the Custom VF page (as per the 3rd screenshot above)?

Please advise on resolving this.

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 2):

I already answered your question here - you can't really change the behavior of any buttons on this bar - Change Server, Reload, Clear Cookies

If you believe this is a bug or needs to be changed, please raise it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch).